# How to receive input name by script in the toolbox on QGIS 3.14?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, toolbox

In **QGIS 3.4.7** I have a script that I use **in the toolbox** and one of the steps is to store the name of the input tiff in a variable. I accomplish this perfectly with this part of the code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer
        
class tiffname(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):    
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer('tiff', 'TIFF', defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(25, model_feedback)
     
        NAMETIFF = parameters['tiff'].name()
        
        feedback.pushInfo(NAMETIFF)
        
        return {}

    def name(self):
        return 'tiffname'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'tiffname'

    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing2', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return tiffname()
```

However in **QGIS 3.14** I get this error:

> NAMETIFF = parameters['tiff'].name()
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

How to call name() in this version?

Answer (score 1):

I am testing your script and this work for me:
`NAMETIFF = str(parameters['tiff'])`

And when run the code finish without errors.

Comment: Great. But with a file called "raster" the answer is raster_7cab7d12_876f_4143_8898_21612deacb72. Any other idea?